# How to initialize a list inside a constructor?

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I have an assignment where I need to initialize a list inside a constructor class, however I am not sure how to put the parameters in for the Main class.

This is the code that I have so far.

```
public CoinSorter(String currency, int maxCoinIn, int minCoinIn, List<Integer> coinList) {
this.currency = currency;
this.maxCoinIn = maxCoinIn;
this.minCoinIn = minCoinIn;
coinList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
coinList.add(10);
coinList.add(20);
coinList.add(50);
coinList.add(100);
coinList.add(200);}
```

and the main class code is

```
CoinSorter cs = new CoinSorter("£", 10000, 0);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The constructor probably shouldn't have the `coinList` argument.  And if it doesn't already, the `CoinSorter` class should contain a `List<Integer> coinList` member.

Comment: What do I put in the member? Thank you for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CoinSorter cs = new CoinSorter("£", 10000, 0);
    }
}
```

```
public class CoinSorter {
    public String currency;
    public int maxCoinIn, int minCoinIn;
    public List<Integer> coinList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public CoinSorter(String currency, int maxCoinIn, int minCoinIn) {
        this.currency = currency;
        this.maxCoinIn = maxCoinIn;
        this.minCoinIn = minCoinIn;

        this.coinList.addAll(Arrays.asList(10, 20, 50, 100, 200));
    }
}
```